# How can I fix this undefined error even though I set a value for it?

Tags: javascript

I'm having this problem and I can't find any solutions maybe you guys can help?

Why can't I access this._activeScene? it always returns undefined even though I already set a value for this._activeScene

```
class SceneManager {
    constructor() {
        this._activeScene = null;
    }

    init() {
        let loop = setInterval(function() {

            console.log(this._activeScene);
            // Returns undefined.

            if(this._activeScene != null) {
                const self = this._activeScene;
                self.options.update();
                self.options.render();
            }
        }, 16.66);
    }

    setScene(scene) {
        this._activeScene = scene;
        this._activeScene.options.initialize()
    }

    get activeScene() {return this._activeScene;}
}

let sceneManager = new SceneManager();
sceneManager.init();

let gameScene = new Scene();

sceneManager.setScene(gameScene);
```

Comment: POssible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: just use arrow function like
`
 init = () => {}
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`this` in this context is not the class instance. The problem here is scope.

The most actual correct solution would be to use arrow functions, which don't bind their own scope, but inherit it from the parent one, which in this case is the instance of SceneManager.

The code would look like this:

```
class SceneManager {
    constructor() {
        this._activeScene = null;
    }

    init() {
        // As suggested by Liam
        // ES6 arrow functions will automatically inherit the current scope
        // as their scope
        let loop = setInterval(() => {

            console.log(this._activeScene);
            // Will no longer output undefined, will output null instead

            if(this._activeScene != null) {
                const self = this._activeScene;
                self.options.update();
                self.options.render();
            }
        }, 16.66);
    }

    setScene(scene) {
        this._activeScene = scene;
        this._activeScene.options.initialize()
    }

    get activeScene() {return this._activeScene;}
}

let sceneManager = new SceneManager();
sceneManager.init();

let gameScene = new Scene();

sceneManager.setScene(gameScene);
```

Other "older" solution would be to use the `let that = this;` trick, which is a well known way to transfer the scope.

```
class SceneManager {
    constructor() {
        this._activeScene = null;
    }

    init() {
        let that = this;
        let loop = setInterval(function() {

            console.log(that._activeScene);
            // now outputs null

            if(that._activeScene != null) {
                const self = that._activeScene;
                self.options.update();
                self.options.render();
            }
        }, 16.66);
    }

    setScene(scene) {
        this._activeScene = scene;
        this._activeScene.options.initialize()
    }

    get activeScene() {return this._activeScene;}
}

let sceneManager = new SceneManager();
sceneManager.init();

let gameScene = new Scene();

sceneManager.setScene(gameScene);
```

Comment: You need to explain what you've changed and why or else we're all playing spot the difference

Comment: Accidentally I copied the text and not only the code. The solution is the let that = this;

Comment: You had a lot of typos

Comment: a more up to date why of doing this, BTW, is to use arrow functions as they transfer scope into the function. I'll give you a plus one as your correct (I'm not sure this really warrants -2) though I still think this needs more explanation

Comment: This actually WORKED! I'm struggling with this for 3 days Thanks a lot! Have a nice day man.

Answer (score 2):

So this is a question of scope, when you create an anonymous function it's in the global scope E.G `function(){};` not the scope of your class instance.
This is one of the cases for using arrow functions `() => {}` because they run in the scope they are created in, however, arrow functions are an ES6 feature so if you need to do it without ES6 you can use the [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method

**ES6 Version**

```
let loop = setInterval(()=>{ // using arrow functions

    console.log(this._activeScene);
    // Returns undefined.

    if(this._activeScene != null) {
        const self = this._activeScene;
        self.options.update();
        self.options.render();
    }
}, 16.66); // not sure you can have 16.66 milliseconds
```

**Non ES6 using .bind**

```
var loop = setInterval((function() {

    console.log(this._activeScene);
    // Returns undefined.

    if(this._activeScene != null) {
        const self = this._activeScene;
        self.options.update();
        self.options.render();
    }
}).bind(this), 16.66); 
 // using .bind create a pointer to the function in the scope of the given var 
 // so in this case we're putting the function in the scope of this 
 // not sure you can have 16.66 milliseconds
```